# Prolog: Predicate that checks yes \= yes outputs yes

Tags: prolog

```
foo(X) :-
    bar(X) \= baz(X).

?- bar(2).
yes
?- baz(2).
yes
?- foo(2).
yes
```

Why does `foo(2)` output yes? If we query `yes \= yes` we get a no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bar(X) \= bar(X)` we also get a no. But `baz` is not `bar`.

In Prolog, there is no "evaluation" of terms. Terms are terms.

- If we *call* `bar(X)` we get `X=2` back (evidently).
- If we call `bar(2)` we get a yes back.
- If we call `1 \= 2` we get a yes back.
- If we call `bar \= baz` we get a yes back.

Same if we call `bar(1) \= baz(2)` or `bar(2) \= baz(2)` or `bar(X) \= baz(X)`.

The `\=`  predicate means "can't be unified". `yes` *can* be unified with `yes`, but `bar(2)` can not be unified with `baz(2)`. Same with `X` instead of `2`.

The `\=` is the predicate being called here, and both `bar(X)` and `baz(X)` are its arguments -- which are symbolic terms.

There is no automatic "evaluation" of terms in Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

`foo(2)` outputs `yes` because [`\=/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%3D)/2) succeeds when it **cannot** unify the left argument with the right argument.

The left argument is `bar(2)` and the right one is `baz(2)` so they will not unify as the principal functor of each term is diffent (`bar` vs `baz`). It doesn't matter the the argument (`2`) is the same for both terms.